# Distribution of the Heaviside function

Tags: improper-integrals, distribution-theory

> $h_n$ is a function such that for every test $\varphi$ is $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h_n(x) \varphi (x)dx\rightarrow H(\varphi).$ Then  $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h'_n(x) \varphi (x)dx\rightarrow \varphi(0)$.

I would start with the following facts

(1) $H(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \delta(t)dt$ then  $\frac{dH}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^x \delta(t)dt=\delta(x)$

(2) The general Heaviside distribution is given by $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}H(x) \varphi (x)dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty} \varphi (x)dx$

Now replace $f$ by $h_n$, since $h_n'$ exists $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h(x) \varphi (x)dx\rightarrow \frac{d}{dx} H(x)=\delta(x)$

I know that if $\delta[x]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\varphi(x)dx$ then $\delta[\varphi]=\varphi(0)$, because f this it seems that the former limit shouldn't be $\delta(x)$ but $\delta (\varphi)$.

Where is it wrong?

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of anything you wrote past the first line in in (2) and there are multiple expressions that don't make any sense.

Comment: For instance, even the $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n(x)\varphi(x)dx \to H(x)$ in the premise makes no sense. Do you mean $\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n(x)\varphi(x)dx \to \int_{-\infty}^\infty H(x)\varphi(x)dx$?

Comment: For when you get the problem statement straight, my hint is: integrate by parts.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen That's what I would expect, but no. There was however a typo in the statement. The problem says "Let $h_n$" be differentiable functions such that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}h_n(x)\varphi(x) dx\rightarrow H(\varphi)$ for every $\varphi\in D(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Doesn't follow from (1) that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h_n(x)\varphi(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h_n'(x)\varphi(x)dx\rightarrow H'(x)=\delta(\varphi)$. I am still not sure about having $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h_n(x)\varphi(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h_n'(x)\varphi(x)dx$

Comment: (re 1st) The definition of $H(\varphi)$ is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty H(x) \varphi(x) dx = \int_0^\infty \varphi(x) dx,$ isn't it?  (re 2nd) This is what I'm talking about... what does $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n(x)\varphi(x)dx$ even mean? $x$ is a dummy variable in the integration so the expression you're differentiating has no dependence on $x$...  taken literally, that derivative is just zero.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see what you mean, You're right. It doesn't makes sense. I'll delete that.
But it seems natural that if $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h_n(x) \varphi (x)dx\rightarrow H(\varphi)$ then $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h_n'(x) \varphi (x)dx\rightarrow H'(\varphi)=\delta(\varphi)=\varphi(0)$. I still don't see it as immediate.

I'm sorry. I don't understand your hint of integrating by parts. I could have $\int h'(x)\varphi(x)=\varphi(x)h(x)-\int h(x) \varphi'(x)$. I don't see how it makes the solution closer.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}h_n'(x) \varphi (x)dx\rightarrow H'(\varphi)$ is it evident? I'm not too sure.

Comment: (1st) I'm not claiming anything is 'immediate' but again you seem to be manipulating expressions without care. For instance $\int h'(x) \varphi(x) = \varphi(x)h(x) = \varphi(x) h(x) -\int h(x)\phi'(x)$ doesn't make much sense (with definite integrals). There is an $x$ on the RHS but not the left. Instead, use whatever decay property  of test functions you have (compact support?) to write $\int h'(x)\varphi(x) = -\int h(x)\varphi'(x).$ (2) Again what does $H'(\varphi)$ even mean? If you mean $\delta(\phi)$ then it's what you are asked to prove, so it isn't evident in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using integration by parts, properties of the test functions, the assumption of the problem, and FTC, we have $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty h'_n(x)\varphi(x) dx = \lim_{n\to \infty}-\int_{-\infty}^\infty h_n(x)\varphi'(x)dx  = -\int_0^\infty\varphi'(x)dx = \varphi(0)$$